# There are 50 students and each has a probability of 0.6 of getting perfect on the exam,what is the probability of at least 20 of them getting perfect?

Tags: probability

I'm making up questions to practice probability. I know this is very much like a dice probability question (what is the probability of x dice rolling 2, for example), which is exactly why I chose it. I can't visualize such a thing beyond the scope of dice.

Anyway, here's my reasoning so far: we're operating in booleans so there are only two possibilities: perfect or not perfect on the test. So I need to figure out how many permutations of perfect and not perfect there are when at least 20 get perfect. 50 choose 20 would give me the number of ways exactly 20 people can get perfect (and if i divide it by all possible outcomes it would give me the probability of 20 people getting perfect).

The amount of possible outcomes is 2^50 because there are 2 possible outcomes per student and there are 50 of them.

If I do the sum of 20 choose 50 all the way to 50 choose 50, I'll have the number of possible ways we can have at least 20 students get perfect. I think that dividing this by 2^50 would work only if it was a 50/50 chance of getting perfect.

So where do I bring in the 0.6? I have a feeling I'm on the right track but I'm not entirely sure.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The number $X$ of students that will get perfect on the exam in a total of 50 students is a random variable that has the binomial distribution with parameters $n=50$ and $p=0.6$. In symbols $$X \sim Bin(n=40, p=0.6)$$ You want to calculate the probability $P(X\ge20)$. Due to each computational complexity you can use the [normal approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Normal_approximation) of the binomial distribution to calculate it. (Not very good choice of numbers to practice in probability...:)

Comment: Thank you. I haven't actually taken a probability course yet, so that article is new to me. I will definitely read it and learn how to do normal approximation.

Comment: That is already for more advanced students. Go first for the binomial distribution and choose easier numbers!! Good luck